# Question2Answer Unknown table engine 'Innodb'

Tags: question2answer

There is problem in viewing tables in PHP my admin it shows me this error

> Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'

and the script don't open tells me

> connection was reset

from couple of days I suddnly found one of my databases has 13 gb size.
I removed it, but the broblems on server begin from this day
and I can't find mysql log file

I use centos 6 with whm cpanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the logfile and restart MySQL
Also make sure innodb_buffer_pool_size setting in my.ini is lower than RAM available on your server.